# curses KEY_RIGHT not recognised

Tags: python, curses

I'm trying wrap my head around the basics of Python `curses` and to build a minimum working program that detects arrow key presses.

Why does `curses.KEY_RIGHT` not appear to be detected in the following code please?

```
import curses

def main(win):
    win.nodelay(False)
    key= ""
    while key != "q": 
       key = win.getkey() 
       if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
           win.addstr("You pressed RIGHT")
       else:
           win.addstr(str(key)) 

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getkey` returns the key converted to a string, while `curses.KEY_RIGHT` is an integer. There are two ways to proceed:

- If you replace `win.getkey()` with `win.getch()`, the program does what you expect (and prints the integers in the `else` case). You would compare against `ord('q')` (which is an integer again) to recognize the user trying to quit.
- Replacing `key == curses.KEY_RIGHT` with `key == "KEY_RIGHT"` would also do the trick.

The [howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#user-input) has more on the difference between `getkey` and `getch`.